# Receive error message using deploydeploymentgroup [REP_55035] An error occurred during deployment. Failed to connect to the repository agent

Tags: xml, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are scripting our Informatica 10.2 Deployment Group process and it fails at the deploydeploymentgroup statement with these errors.  I connect to the source repository successfully beforehand.   These commands are executed on Linux machine.  I've entered them in manually and run them via a script I've tried connecting to the target twice and tried the -t option on the connect.  Connecting to the source repository seems to be successful according to the messages.  No matter what I try I still fail on the deploydeploymentgroup statement.  Anything between { } is redacted information.

```
[REP_55035] An error occurred during deployment.  Failed to connect to the {SOURCE_REPO} repository agent. Failed to execute deploydeploymentgroup
```

These are the sequence of commands and their responses.  The DEPLOYOPTIONS is an XML file and we are using depcntl.dtd file Version 8.

```
pmrep>
   Informatica(r) PMREP, version [10.2.0 HotFix2], build [1911.0401], LINUX 64-bit 
   Copyright (c) 1993-2019 Informatica LLC. All Rights Reserved. 
   See patents at https://www.informatica.com/legal/patents.html. 
   Invoked at Wed Feb 17 14:45:20 2021

pmrep>connect -r {SOURCE_REPO} -h {SOURCE_SERVER} -o {SOURCE_PORT} -n {SOURCE_INFA_DOMAIN_USER} -s {SOURCE_SECURITY_DOMAIN} -x {SOURCE_PASSWORD}

   Connected to repository {SOURCE_REPO} in {SOURCE_DOMAIN} as user {SOURCE_INFA_DOMAIN_USER}
   connect completed successfully.

pmrep>deploydeploymentgroup -p {DG_NAME} -c {DEPLOYOPTIONS} -r {TARGET_REPO} -h {TARGET_SERVER} -o {TARGET_PORT} -n {TARGET_INFA_DOMAIN_USER} -x {TARGET_PASSWORD} 

   An error occurred while accessing the repository [Failed to connect to the EDO_PCREP_DEV repository agent.] [REP_55035] An error occurred during deployment.  Failed to connect to the EDO_PCREP_DEV
   repository agent. Failed to execute deploydeploymentgroup.
```

Comment: Looks like its not able to connetc to the repo. Are you issuing command in the localhost? if not check if you can reach infa node from where ever you are issuing this command.

Comment: I am running the command on the local host.

Comment: can you paste exact `connect` command?

Comment: Here is 1 iteration$pmrep 
cleanup
connect -r EDO_PP_QAT -h infelhq013 -o 16017 -n auto_deploy -s Native -x redacted password
connect -r EDO_PP_DEV -h infelhd013 -o 16017 -n auto_deploy -s Native -x redacted password
deploydeploymentgroup -p CLDW_4572_CMA_TCR_2021_Final -c /HOME/informatica/infa/deployoptions/deployOptions_CLDW_4572_CMA_TCR_2021_Final.xml -r EDO_PP_QAT -h infelhq013 -o 16017 -n auto_deploy -x redacted password
exit

Comment: Here is another      $pmrep 
cleanup
connect -r EDO_PP_DEV -h infelhd013 -o 16017 -n auto_deploy -s Native -x redacted password
deploydeploymentgroup -p CLDW_4572_CMA_TCR_2021_Final -c /HOME/informatica/infa/deployoptions/deployOptions_CLDW_4572_CMA_TCR_2021_Final.xml -r EDO_PP_QAT -h infelhq013 -o 16017 -n auto_deploy -x redacted password
exit
EOF